# Import Keras does not work

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am just doing :

```
import keras
```

and I get a long error message :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-88d96843a926> in <module>()
 ----> 1 import keras

~\Anaconda3\envs\test_tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>()
        1 from __future__ import absolute_import
        2 
  ----> 3 from . import utils
        4 from . import activations
        5 from . import applications

  ~\Anaconda3\envs\test_tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py 
  in <module>()
        3 from . import generic_utils
        4 from . import data_utils
        ----> 5 from . import io_utils
        6 from . import conv_utils
        7 

 ~\Anaconda3\envs\test_tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\io_utils.py in <module>()
         9 import six
         10 try:
         ---> 11     import h5py
         12 except ImportError:
         13     h5py = None

  ~\Anaconda3\envs\test_tensorflow\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py in <module>()
          32         raise
          33 
          ---> 34 _errors.silence_errors()
          35 
          36 from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters

          AttributeError: module 'h5py._errors' has no attribute 'silence_errors'
```

Anyone has an idea on how to fix it ?

Working on Windows 10 and using Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling h5py by using:

```
pip uninstall h5py
pip install h5py
```

Answer (score -1):

You may need to import `tensorflow` directly:

Try

```
import tensorflow
```

before you

```
import keras
```

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your answer